# preg_match - what's wrong with this code?

Tags: php, preg-match

`$message` contains two different Youtube videos. The code below works but the problem is that the end result produces two iframes with the same video ID (the first video). How can I solve this problem?

```
$message = 'This is a text with 2 Youtube videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxwMjB-Skao csassasas http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWEwWECAokU Enf of text';

$reg_exUrl_youtube = "/(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'> \r\n]+)(?![^<]*>)/";
if (preg_match($reg_exUrl_youtube, $message, $youtubeUrlData) ) {
$message = preg_replace($reg_exUrl_youtube, "<iframe title=\"{$youtubeUrlData[1]}\" class=\"youtube\" src=\"[qqqqq].youtube.com/embed/{$youtubeUrlData[1]}\" frameborder=\"0\" allowFullScreen></iframe>", $message);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to check the string before with `preg_match`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **The fix for your code** is to use $1 instead of {$youtubeUrlData[1]} in the **preg_replace**() call:

```
$message = preg_replace($reg_exUrl_youtube, "<iframe title=\"$1\" class=\"youtube\" src=\"[qqqqq].youtube.com/embed/$1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowFullScreen></iframe>", $message);
```

2) Another implementation with **preg_replace_callback**(), which is very reliable from my experience, just as an example:

```
$message = 'This is a text with 2 Youtube videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxwMjB-Skao csassasas http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWEwWECAokU Enf of text';

$reg_exUrl_youtube = "/(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'> \r\n]+)(?![^<]*>)/";

$finalString = preg_replace_callback($reg_exUrl_youtube, function($matches) {
    return "<iframe title=\"{$matches[1]}\" class=\"youtube\" src=\"[qqqqq].youtube.com/embed/{$matches[1]}\" frameborder=\"0\" allowFullScreen></iframe>";
}, $message);

echo htmlentities($finalString);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why use an error prone regex?

Much simpler:

```
$message = 'This is a text with 2 Youtube videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxwMjB-Skao csassasas http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWEwWECAokU Enf of text';

$a=explode(' ',$message);
foreach($a as $v){
    if(strpos($v,'http')!==false && strpos($v,'youtube')!==false){
    $res[]=$v;
    }
}   
echo var_dump($res);
```